# Android selector showing error

Tags: android

In my android xml file I have one **edittext** .I was trying to customize that **edittext** the xml is looks like :--

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:background="@layout/textbox001"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usernameicon"
          / >
```

and in layout the **textbox001** is:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#e4e4e2"
                android:endColor="#d5d5d5"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#282a2f" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
        android:endColor="#e4e4e2"
        android:startColor="#d5d5d5"
        android:angle="270"
 />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#282a2f" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

but its showing errors in selector..i.e:--

```
element selector does not have  required attribute android:layout_width 
element selector does not have  required attribute android:layout_height
```

Where is the problem???how can I correct it??
In xml graphic it is also showing that:--

```
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)
```

Comment: where you closed `</EditText>` tag?

Comment: Nothing happens..still showing the error..

Comment: @Sandiprana I tried your code.It works for me. Ignore both the warnings.

Comment: I have closed it..sorry,I have edited the question.

Comment: @Sandiprana See its not error merely warning.in the xml preview Run your code. It will works just fine.

Comment: Ok..thank you @Mr. smith...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working fine only :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#e4e4e2"
                android:endColor="#d5d5d5"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#282a2f" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
        android:endColor="#e4e4e2"
        android:startColor="#d5d5d5"
        android:angle="270"
 />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#282a2f" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you should place your selector file in drawable folder, not in layout folder !